# Select attribute in html not working as expected in Angular app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a front end made in Angular.
I am basically building a form now and having a problem with select type.

```
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.$submitted && form[field.id].$invalid }" ng-if="field.type === 'select'">
                <!-- <label for="{{field.id}}">{{field.title.substr(field.title.indexOf('.') + 2)}}</label><br> -->
                <label for="{{field.id}}">{{field.title}}</label>
                <br>
                <select ng-model="formData[field.id]" value="{{value}}" ng-options="value as value.title for value in field.values"></select>
                <p class="form-group-note" ng-if="field.info" ng-bind="field.info"></p>

                <div ng-show="form.$submitted" ng-cloack>
                    <span class="help-block" ng-show="form['{{field.id}}'].$error.required" ng-if="field.validations.required">Please enter a value, this field is required</span>
                </div>
    </div>
```

The JSON file I'm feeding to the view is like following:

```
{
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": "4_2",
            "title": "Passport",
            "sections": [
                {
                    "id": "4_2_section",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "id": "select_id",
                                                        "title": "Select type of question",
                            "type": "select",
                            "info": "Always select \"Yes\"",
                            "size": {
                                "width": 100,
                                "height": 1
                            },
                            "validations": {
                                "required": true
                            },
                            "values": [
                                {
                                    "id": 0,
                                    "title": "Not Selected"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 1,
                                    "title": "Yes"
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 2,
                                    "title": "No"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Whenever user selects something in Select type of question, selected value is being saved in $localStorage for front-end model persistence.

Function called to save data in localStorage(basically I'm saving data in a varibla called `formData` and saving this in `localStorage`):

```
      function set (data) {
        if (hasLocalStorage) {
          localStorage.setItem(key, data);
        }
      }

  FormDataService.save = function (formData) {
    var previousFormData = get();
    var currentFormData = JSON.stringify(formData);

    if (previousFormData !== currentFormData) {
      set(currentFormData);
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  };
```

The problem I'm having is that the data is being saved in following format:

```
"select_id":{"id":0,"title":"Not Selected"}
```

I would like to save the data as following format:

```
"select_id":"Not Selected"
```

How can I just extract "Not Selected" and save it in the local storage?

Comment: function set (data) {
        if (hasLocalStorage) {
          localStorage.setItem(key, data.title);
        }
      }

Comment: @agustaf I can't do that since I need data on other parts.